# TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC] and datetime in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I've got the following data:

```
import schedule, datetime
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dfori = [
    {'id': '1','time': '2023-05-06T23:00:02Z'},
    {'id': '2','time': '2023-05-05T00:00:23Z'},
    {'id': '3','time': '2023-05-04T00:00:30Z'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(dfori, columns = [
    'id','result_video_upload_time'])
```

I want a code that will cycle through the entire **dataframe** and filter out values unless they're between X and Y.

Here are the steps I have taken:

```
start_date = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond = 0)

end_date = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours = 1))



dfpre = df.loc[((df['date'] > end_date) & (df['date'] < start_date))]

dfpost = df.loc[((df['date'] > end_date) & (df['date'] < start_date))]
```

This code works if I turn my `datetime.utcnow()` into an object and break it apart. But breaking it apart only works if the date doesn't need to change, with UTC as the time zone, that code breaks after 7 PM.

The error this produces:

> **TypeError**: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC] and datetime

I attempted to follow other posts and tried to slap `.tx_convert(None)` on my dataframe like so:

```
df['date'] =df['date'].dt.tz_convert(None)
```

I didn't think it would work as we're already in UTC time. Anywho, I'm unsure of how to proceed from here.

Comment: Try `start_date = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond = 0).dt.date`  `end_date = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours = 1)).dt.date` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use timezone aware Timestamps if your dataframe's datetime is time zone aware (Z means UTC). Here's a MRE:

```py
import pandas as pd

# --> dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"id": "1", "time": "2023-05-06T23:00:02Z"},
        {"id": "2", "time": "2023-05-05T00:00:23Z"},
        {"id": "3", "time": "2023-05-04T00:00:30Z"},
    ],
    columns=["id", "time"],
)
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
# <-- dummy data

# you could also use pd.Timestamp("now", tz="UTC") here:
start_date = pd.Timestamp("2023-05-07", tz="UTC").replace(microsecond=0)
end_date = start_date - pd.Timedelta(days=2)

dfpre = df.loc[((df["date"] > end_date) & (df["date"] < start_date))]
dfpost = df.loc[((df["date"] > end_date) & (df["date"] < start_date))]
```

```py
print(dfpre)
  id                  time                      date
0  1  2023-05-06T23:00:02Z 2023-05-06 23:00:02+00:00
1  2  2023-05-05T00:00:23Z 2023-05-05 00:00:23+00:00

print(dfpost)
  id                  time                      date
0  1  2023-05-06T23:00:02Z 2023-05-06 23:00:02+00:00
1  2  2023-05-05T00:00:23Z 2023-05-05 00:00:23+00:00
```

In general, avoid `datetime.utcnow()` - some [background info](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html). pandas has all you need.

Comment: Since `dfpre.equals(dfpost)` gives `True`, I wonder what's the purpose of having the same output twice. The OP's logic is not fully clear (*at least for me*)..

Comment: @Timeless I've focused my answer on the error described in the OP; but you have a good point there :) I've had to modify some things already to make this a somewhat useful example...

Comment: Yes I saw that +1 and you're right, in most of the time, I think there is no need to use external datetime *modules* and/or *libraries* when manipulating datetimes with `pandas` ;).

Comment: I appreciate your help in this matter. My issue is I need the full date time. Because YouTube posts in UTC, any videos released after 7PM automatically becomes a new day, so I need the hour to keep track of this. Also, this code is to be used daily, so I can't have a string. I've tried using date time objects such as:         dobj = datetime.strptime(dstring, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")  But nothing works when we have to take both time and date as a factor.

Comment: @user21090678 no need to use the datetime module, stick with pandas, use e.g. `pd.Timestamp("now", tz="UTC")` to get the current UTC time (daily use?). See the comment in my example code. But: that's just an example - you'll have to adapt it to your actual needs.

Comment: My friend, I've been trying to get datetime to work for a month. This is the second time I've asked this question because nobody would answer it and I shamelessly deleted it. I always knew it was so simple, but nothing I did worked. I didn't even know that pandas could do this. I shall sing of your wisdom to my children.

Comment: @user21090678 no worries ^^ glad I could help.